# Order of adding constraints when solving an SMT problem

Tags: smt

Let's say I have a pretty simple SMT problem - some free variables and some constrains `С` on them. I also have an extra constraint `EC`. I want to prefer a solution when both `C` an `EC` are met and fallback to `C`-only solution if this is impossible.

How should I call `check-sat` in this case? Intuition tells me something like this:

```
(assert C)
(push)
(assert EC)
(check-sat)
<dance happy dance if it worked, or ...>
(pop)
(check-sat)
```

But I suspect that `pop` will wipe all the knowledge solver has mined, and the second `check-sat` will start from scratch.

I can try

```
(assert C)
(check-sat)
(push)
(assert EC)
(check-sat)
<dance happy dance if it worked, or ...>
(pop)
(check-sat)
```

The question is - can I be sure than the last `(check-sat)` will be a no-op, because there already was a call to `check-sat` with the same constraint set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> But I suspect that pop will wipe all the knowledge solver has mined, and the second check-sat will start from scratch.

Not necessarily. Learned clauses that depend only on `C` do not need to be discarded at `pop()`, although it is always safe to do so. This may be solver dependent.

> The question is - can I be sure than the last `(check-sat)` will be a no-op, because there already was a call to check-sat with the same constraint set?

I wouldn't expect an SMT solver to remember that the previous `check-sat` was satisfiable, the previous model or even the previous sequence of decisions that lead to the `SAT` conclusion (after you asserted and checked something else). Nonetheless, the last `check-sat` should be much cheaper than the first check, because learned clauses don't need to be generated twice.

---

Focusing on pure SMT solvers, one option would be to use the API rather than the SMT-LIB interface so that one can simply save the `SAT` model after the first `check-sat` and there is no need of a third `check-sat` after `pop()`.

---

What you probably want is to encode your problem as a **MaxSMT** problem.

> **Definition 2.3.4.** *(Partial Weighted MaxSMT, Partial MaxSMT, Weighted MaxSMT).*
>   A Partial Weighted MaxSMT problem is a pair `<φ_h, φ_s>`
>   where `φ_h` is the set of "hard" T-clauses, and `φ_s` is a
>   collection of positive-weighted "soft" T-clauses of the form
>   `<C_i, w_i>`, and the goal is to find the maximum-weight set
>   of T-clauses `ψ_s`, `ψ_s ⊆ φ_s`, such that `φ_h ∪ ψ_s` is
>   T-satisfiable *[NO06, CFG+10, ABP+11b, CGSS13a]*.
>
> A Partial MaxSMT problem is a Partial Weighted MaxSMT problem
>   in which all "soft" T-clauses in `φ_s` have a unitary weight.
>
> A Weighted MaxSMT problem is a Partial Weighted MaxSMT
>   problem in which the set of "hard" T-clauses `φ_h` is empty.
>
> [[source, p. 40](http://www.patricktrentin.com/data/phd_thesis/main.pdf)]

In this case, you would assert `EC` as one, or more, **soft clauses**.

Let's say `EC` is a list of constraints `ec_1, ..., ec_k`, there are two cases:

- you want all `ec_1, ..., ec_k` to be satisfied at the same time; then you would write:

  ```
  (assert C)
  (assert-soft EC)
  (check-sat)
  (get-model)
  ```
- you want the largest possible subset of `EC` to be satisfied at the same time; then you would write:

  ```
  (assert c)
  (assert-soft ec_1)
  (assert-soft ...)
  (assert-soft ec_k)
  (check-sat)
  (get-model)
  ```

**MaxSMT** is supported by OMT solvers like [Barcelogic](https://barcelogic.com/), [OptiMathSAT](http://optimathsat.disi.unitn.it/) and [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3).

Comment: Indeed, soft asserts is exactly what I want in this case. Many thanks for the answer.